# template overloading resolution rules

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading

Just can't understand what's going on. Is there anyone who can explain these clearly? If so, please give me some clues or keywords to search.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto max (T1 a, T2 b) {
  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

template <typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT max (T1 a, T2 b) {
  std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

void func() {
  auto a = max(4, 7.2); // 1 ? 
  auto b = max<long double>(7.2, 4); // 2 ?
  auto c = max<int>(3.4, 2); // 2 ?
  auto e = max<double, int>(3.4, 2); // 1 ?
}
```

If 2nd max function is not defined, every max call works just fine. On what ground 2nd max is called. What's the rule for it?

Comment: Probably it's pretty apparent to you guys. There are no build problems. I just don't get it how to decide which function is called on every `max` call.

Comment: *please give me some clues or keywords to search.* The keyword you're looking for is probably **Template Type Deduction**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max(4, 7.2)` generates a function from first template because two parameters `<int, double>` are known.
`max<long double>(7.2, 4)` generates a function from second template because three parameters `(long double, double, int)` are known.
`max<int>(4, 7.2)` is the same as before.
`max<double, int>(3.4, 2)` generates a function from first template because the two given template parameters fit to the given values. The two parameters are `<double, int>`

The compiler tries to deduce the types from function call, if no template parameters are given.

Comment: I think that `auto` deduction rules are relevant too, in this case, and worth mentioning.

Comment: I think that `auto` return type does not change template deduction. You could change it to some concrete type. It is used in this example to change the number of template types.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify a template type, the second form is never used, because RT cannot be deduced, and must be specified.

If you do specify a type, and it is different to T1 deduced from the argument then the second form is used.

Note that the first form is actually C++14, not C++11. In C++11 you have to specify the return type one way or another.

The second form is C++11, and might be provided in C++14 for backward compatibility. Also in principle the second form lets you control the widening, but in practice I'm not sure what the second form gets you, as ?: has to resolve to a single size type. [This answers your supplementary question I think]

For example if the two types were signed and unsigned and the return type was double (but you would get a warning), the ?: result would be probably unsigned (or an error), then cast to double, which is unhelpful. Ideally you need a third version to handle signed/unsigned mismatch anyway, if you care - this is a whole can of special case worms to resolve cleanly.

If it was written long-hand with 2 return statements then it would correctly widen both halves. Better yet, if the casts were performed before the comparison...